# Maven Shade Plugin: deploy both artifacts but make shaded one the main

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I use maven shade plugin in the `package` phase and I want that

- the shaded jar becomes the main jar `my-app.jar`
- the original jar is not renamed to `original-my-app.jar` but a custom classifier is applied to it, in particular `my-app:no-deps.jar`
- finally I want that both jars are deployed with `mvn deploy`

My current setup has `<shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>` which makes the shaded jar to be renamed as the main jar of the project and deployed (which is fine) but I don't get the original jar to be deployed and moreover I don't know how to rename it.

Answer (score 3):

You have decided to use `<shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>` which implies that the shaded artifact will become the main artifact.

If you like to have both artifacts you have to use `<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>` which will make add the shaded artifact as a classifier artifact. This will result in having two artifacts one which is the main artifact under the groupId/artifactId and a supplemental artifact which can be addressed by using a classifier. This is by default `shaded` this means having groupId/artifactId/classifier in your pom to use that artifact instead of the main artifact.

Comment: Do you mean that on top of my pom I should add a `shaded` classifier?

Comment: I don't want clients to address my library as `library:shaded`, but I want that the shaded jar becomes the main one